# Specify byte range via query string in Get Object S3 request

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, http-headers

I'm familiar with the Range HTTP header; however, the interface I'm using to query S3 (an img element's .src property) doesn't allow me to specify HTTP headers.

Is there a way for me to specify my desired range via a parameter in the query string?

It doesn't seem like there is, but I'm just holding out a shred of hope before I roll my own solution with ajax requests.

Comment: Sorry to destroy your last shred of hope, but no, there's not a documented way to do this... but also, given that rfc-7233 indicates that `Range:` support is optional in servers and proxies, and that the concept of a "partial" img is not necessarily something browsers might universally understand as a sane concept... what are you trying to accomplish with only a subset of an image's data?

Comment: S3 `PUT` requests are $5 for 1 million. Still, it's an interesting approach you're taking.

Answer (score 24):

Amazon S3 supports Range GET requests, as do some HTTP servers, for example, Apache and IIS.

[How CloudFront Processes Partial Requests for an Object (Range GETs)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RangeGETs.html)

I tried to get my S3 object via cURL:

```sh
curl -r 0-1024 https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myobject -o part1
curl -r 1025-  https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myobject -o part2
cat part1 part2 > myobject
```

and AWS SDK for JavaScript:

```js
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var file = require('fs').createWriteStream('part1');
var params = {
    Bucket: 'mybucket',
    Key: 'myobject',
    Range: 'bytes=0-1024'
};
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);
```

These two methods work fine for me.

[AWS SDK for JavaScript API Reference (getObject)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property)

Comment: in the above example will it download 1024 bytes or 1023? Is the end range value exclusive or inclusive?

Comment: @ShwetabhShekhar appears to be inclusive; in fact `0-1024` gives *1025* bytes, not 1024 or 1023

Comment: RFC 7233: the byte positions specified are inclusive; byte offsets start at zero.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Java Code with AWS V2 SDK

format the range as below

```
var range = String.format("bytes=%d-%d", start, end);
```

and pass it in below api with GetObjectRequest builder

```
 ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> currentS3Obj = client.getObjectAsBytes(GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).range(range).build());
return currentS3Obj.asInputStream();
```